# How to send the message from DialogFlow WebDemo from page javascript

Tags: iframe, dialogflow-es

I have a DialogFlow web demo page with trivial frame code

```html
<iframe
  name = "dialogflow_frame"
  id = "dialogflow_frame"
  allow="microphone;"
  width="350"
  height="230"
  src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/_x_x_x_">
</iframe>
```

This show the embedded DialogFlow chat on my page.

I want to send some message string from my page to chat with some page JavaScript command (for example - some content from this page).

How to send the message from page code? I've try to search the iframe form, but it's doesn't available from code.

```html
<iframe
name = "dialogflow_frame"
id = "dialogflow_frame"
allow="microphone;"
width="350"
height="230"
src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/_x_x_x_"
onload="console.log('onload'); var f=document.getElementById('query'); console.log(f);"
>
```

In this code `f` (search for `query` field) return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access), you can't access the DOM of the iframe from the javascript on your page, so this is not possible.

Comment: Can dialogflow frame listen for some postmessage's ?

Comment: No, it doesn't listen for postmessages.